# What should be (or what can I have) in my layout.js? (next.js running on Amplify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

**next.js on AWS Amplify**

I am using App Router (next.js V13.4.10)
Figma Integrated with Amplify
Github Integrated with Amplify and my VSCode

**I am wanting to set up a thorough template in my layout.js**

- I want the app running ServerSide producing everything possible on the server.
- I would like to have my menu and my footer in the layout at the very least
- I would like them dynamic based on a selectable organisation, and the menu items or a JSON array are store in a public DataStore
- Ultimately I want to data drive the front end; a menu structure based on the organisation that the user selects. e.g. 1 organisation may not have a contactus page and hence do not need a menu option of contactus.

**so I wish to query the organisation table to provide a front-end setup.**
I can do thi;

but the moment **I add ui-components** I then have to have 'use client' at the top of the file due to 'useEffect' somewhere in the components.

**I get this error**

```
You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials
```

**I add 'use client'**

then has an issue with the DataStore, but also want it running server side.

**I get this error:**

```
error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component 
from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
[WARN] 44:10.267 DataStore - Realtime disabled when in a server-side environment
```

I maybe able to remove the ui-components and build my own.
but this seems like a complete waste of the capability of integrated Figma

**Do I just need to remove the buttons etc from those ui-components so that it can run Server Side???**

here is my layout.js:

```
//'use client' //uncomment following the useEffect Error
import './globals.css';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { Organisation } from '@/models';
import { Amplify, AuthModeStrategyType, API, Auth, withSSRContext } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { NavBarHeader2 } from '@/ui-components'
import awsExports from '../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true, DataStore: {
  authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH
}
});

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
const models = await DataStore.query(Organisation);
console.log(models);


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
          <NavBarHeader2/>
          <div className="z-10
```

***UPDATE:***

I added 'use client' to the src\ui-components\index.js file and my 'useEffect' error went away, but I feel like this is not the right solution as it will be updated & removed in the next amplify sync.

**Is there a way to import Client Side only for this particular import?**

I wan't to deliver as per this guide...
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

and essentially I want it included in the UI-component that when something is interactive it uses the Client Side. but not all components need Client Side rendering.
so it would seem like this ui-component library has been delivered for V12 or earlier of next.js???

**So what is the best way to handle this situation?**

Comment: I added 'use client' to the src\ui-components\index.js file
and my 'useEffect' error went away, but I feel like this is not the right solution as it will be updated & removed in the next sync.